# Blaschke product having poles proof

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces, blaschke-products

I am studying Banach Spaces of Analytic Function by Hoffman. Hoffman proves the following theorem:

> The [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) whose zeroes are  \begin{align*} \alpha_{1} ,
>  \alpha_2 , \ldots \end{align*} converges at all points $z \in \mathbb
>  C$ except those in the compact set $K$ consisting of
>
> - the points $z=1/\bar{\alpha}_n$;
> - the points $z$ on the unit circle which are accumulation points of the sequence $(\alpha _n)$.
>
> The convergence is uniform on any closed set $K$ in the plane which is
> disjoint from $K$, and the Blaschke product is thus analytic off $K$.

The author further remarks that the Blaschke product has a pole $1/\bar{\alpha}_n$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ and an essential singularity at the accumulation point of the $\alpha _n$.

I have not been able to prove this, however, I wonder if this follows directly from the the theorem that was mentioned. For the zeroes, it directly follows from the convergence theorem, as mentioned in [Ash's Complex Variables Theorem 6.1.7.](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV6.pdf). How does one go about proving that the Blaschke product has a pole of $1/\bar{\alpha}_n$?

Comment: Isn't it just that the denominator of the factor $$\frac{z-\alpha_n}{1-\overline\alpha_nz}$$ vanishes precisely when $z = 1/\overline\alpha_n$?

Comment: @MPW Yes. For the finite Blaschke product, there is nothing to prove. However, for the infinite case, I do not think this is so trivial.

Comment: Ok. I wonder if it is worth considering the zeros of $1/f$ ?

Comment: @MartinR To show a function $f$ with isolated singularity at $z_0$, $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ iff $|f(z)| \to +\infty$ as $z \to z_0$. But in this case, I need to interchange the limit and the infinite product which is not so clear to me.

Comment: The idea is that $\prod_{k \ne n} \frac{|\alpha_k|}{\alpha_k} \frac{\alpha_k-z}{1-\bar \alpha_k z}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z=1/\bar \alpha_n$.

Comment: @MartinR That is because the zeroes of the Blaschke product must be isolated inside the open unit disc, so, that makes sense. But how does that help?

Comment: Is it clear to you that the Blaschke product is holomorphic in the exterior of the unit disk except at the points $1/\bar \alpha_n$? Are you only asking why the function has a *pole* at that points?

Comment: @MartinR It is clear to me that the the Blaschke product is holomorphic in the exterior of the unit disc except at the points $\frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}_n}$. Yes, that exactly is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blaschke product
$$
B(z) = \prod_{k =1}^\infty \frac{|\alpha_k|}{\alpha_k} \frac{\alpha_k-z}{1-\bar \alpha_k z}
$$
is holomorphic in the exterior of the unit disk except at the points $z=1/\bar \alpha_k$.

Now fix an index $n$ and choose $N \ge n$ so large that $a_k \ne a_n$ for $k > N$. This is always possible because the “Blaschke condition” $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-|a_k|) < \infty $ implies that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \lvert a_k \rvert = 1$. Then
$$
 B(z) = R(z) \cdot \tilde B(z)
$$
where
$$
R(z) = \prod_{k =1}^N \frac{|\alpha_k|}{\alpha_k} \frac{\alpha_k-z}{1-\bar \alpha_k z}
$$
is a rational function, and
$$
\tilde B(z) = \prod_{k =N+1}^\infty \frac{|\alpha_k|}{\alpha_k} \frac{\alpha_k-z}{1-\bar \alpha_k z}
$$
is again a Blaschke product. $\tilde B$ is holomorphic in the exterior of the unit disk except at the points $1/\bar \alpha_k$, $k > N$. In particular, $\tilde B$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $1/\bar \alpha_n$.

So $B$ is the product of a rational function $R$ with a pole at $1/\bar \alpha_n$ and a function $\tilde B$ which is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $1/\bar \alpha_n$. It follows that $B$ has a pole at $1/\bar \alpha_n$.

More precisely, if $\alpha_n$ occurs $p$ times in the sequence $(\alpha_k)$ then $B$ has a $p$-fold pole at $1/\bar \alpha_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a small follow up question: The author says that essential singularity occurs at the accumulation points of the zeroes of the $(\alpha _n)$, however, the accumulation points of the zeroes and the poles are the same and so if I am not mistaken the accumulation point of the poles cannot possibly be a isolated singularity. So, does it even make sense to talk about an essential singularity at the accumulation points of the zeroes?

Comment: @AshishKujur: That is a good question. An essential singularity (as I know it) is an isolated singularity. Perhaps that book defines it differently.